# HTML Stylesheet interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am making a demo site. I am using multiple style sheets and taking what I like from each of them to build a site for learning purposes. Now my problem is that there's a line in the meta data which prevents my modals from closing, my modals lock in place due to it, but I also need it to design the other parts the way I want them to be.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css"> <!-- EFFECTING CLICKING OUT TO CLOSE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css"> <!-- EFFECTING WORDS IN MODALS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I attempted to get rid of each line to see specifically what they did and how they effected my program. Some either effects the modals and the ability to click out of them, or erasing all text within in the modals.

I had an idea to make separate html files and calling them into a main file, giving each of them different meta data. Would this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try stick to bootstrap and copy/paste only the parts you need from the w3 css files and add your own. Or look for a bootstrap theme compatible. Or write your own css using only what you need.

Comment: If you are comfortable enough with navigating css files, you really should extract out the stuff you need from each css file and put them into a single file. If you are not comfortable enough with navigating css files, then I REALLY suggest you do this. That would be a much better learning experience, honestly. Plus, your end result would be non-conflicting CSS. 2 birds with 1 stone

Comment: I would strongly advise against hot-linking to another website's CSS files, unless of course they're part of a CDN designed for that purpose. Can you not simply extract the styles you need from them instead of loading an entire styelsheet for one aspect of it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to extract the CSS's file alone because my reference is from w3schools.com (A good learning place I have found for html/bootstrap) and copy pasted their code into my document. Then I was trying to rearrange it and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose as others mentioned in the comments to keep just the essential parts on the head section. That means that it is much easier for you as you will have better control on your code if you write your own css and load it on your html. Stick with Bootstrap as it gives already the basic layout for a webpage that can also be responsive.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--Links to CSS, Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your-external-css-file.css"/>
</head>
```

Your head tags should include something like the previous sample.

Answer (score 0):

The referred files (/w3.css and /w3-theme-black.css) don't have any conflicting classes between them. The rendering conflict may be caused by how you implemented such classes.

You can easily test this theory by reversing the order to which you refer to the .css files, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
```

If by changing the order of the css you get the reverse experience than it's a css conflict, but I doubt.  Then the next option would be to take a closer look at how you employed the css classes.

Also I would advice to move the "<meta charset="utf-8">" above the bootstrap css files.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a closer look at the code you've posted I noticed that you have 2 references to the bootstrap/3.3.6. You might have to play with the files order too.